# How do we 'dispose' a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small application I am developing to learn AJAX and JavaScript. In this I have method `saveData()` that is triggered when a `save` button is clicked. All is working fine, but I realized that the page was refreshing so I searched the web and found the JavaScript method `event.preventDefault()`. This method worked fine. But that got me into problem, my modal dialog was staying open instead of closing. Again, I found `hide` method to `"close"` the modal. That solved it, **BUT** when I click the to open the modal it is bringing me the recent data I sent to the DB. I am from Java background and I began to think that `hide`did not **kill** the modal.

**My question:** Is there a method to completely destroy the modal the way is done with `JFrame.dispose()`method in Java?

**The code I was using is below:**

```
   function saveData(){
    var name=$('#nm').val();
    var email=$('#em').val();
    var phone=$('#hp').val();
    var address=$('#al').val();
    event.preventDefault();//prevent the page from refresh
    $.ajax({
       type:"post",
       url:"server.php?p=add",
       data:{nm:name,em:email,hp:phone,al:address},
       success: function(data){
        viewData();
        $('#addData').modal('hide');//close the modal.
       }
    });

  }
```

Comment: Add to the button type="button" to prevent the refreshing.

Comment: @ShalomPeles It works I see, but now to 'dispose' modal

Comment: You never disposes a Bootstrap modal. All what you can is hide it and show it

Answer (score 0):

You can just clear the values in your input tag every time you open the modal.

Comment: You know how to use jquery, right? Put an id to your input tag. Then every time you open your modal include this code - `$('#idOfYourInput').val('');` to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

I already faced this problem with the modal for clear all value.but i using the follow code after hiding the modal.

My modal id is `#modal`

```
$('#modal').hide();
$('#modal')
    .find("input,textarea,select")
       .val('')
       .end()
    .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
       .prop("checked", "")
       .end();
```

if you have any prolem then you can refer the link that may help you : [How to clear all input fields in bootstrap modal when clicking data-dismiss button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151044/how-to-clear-all-input-fields-in-bootstrap-modal-when-clicking-data-dismiss-butt)