# Form inside Boostrap Modal does not reset

Tags: javascript, meteor, bootstrap-modal, adminlte

I am using below click event to reset Form.

```
'click .resetBulkAssignForm' : function(events, template){
    console.log('Reset', $(".bulkAssignForm")[0]);
    $(".bulkAssignForm")[0].reset();
    $(".bulkAssignForm").find("select").val("");
    $('#firmName').select2('data', null);
},
```

I also tried most of the answers available on SO to solve this issue.

**Question:** How to reset form inside Bootstrap Modal?

Below is the image of the modal with console output.

[image]

> NOTE: I am using AdminLTE 2.3.11, Select2. Also kindly take a note that I have already tried solutions in SO links like [how-to-clear-all-input-fields-in-bootstrap-modal-when-clicking-data-dismiss-butt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151044/how-to-clear-all-input-fields-in-bootstrap-modal-when-clicking-data-dismiss-butt), [how-to-reset-form-body-in-bootstrap-modal-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827262/how-to-reset-form-body-in-bootstrap-modal-box)

Adding HTML Code in case you need to see.

```
<div id="myBulkModal" class="modal fade modal-primary" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h2 class="modal-title">Bulk Assignment</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <section class="content">
             <form class="bulkAssignForm">
               <fieldset>
                 <div class="row">
                    <input type="hidden" id="taskIdInput" value="{{getTaskId}}" />
                 </div>
                 <div class="row">
                   <div class="input-group col-sm-12">
                     <label for="firmName">Firms</label><br />
                     <select id="firmName" multiple class="form-control input-lg" required>
                       {{#each firmNamesFromAssignment}}
                          <option value="{{value}}">{{label}}</option>
                       {{/each}}
                     </select>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <br />
                 <div class="row">
                   <div class="input-group col-sm-12">
                     <label for="assignee">Assignee</label><br />
                     <select id="assignee" class="form-control input-lg" required>
                       <option  selected="selected" value="">Select Option</option>
                       {{#each usersSelect2}}
                          <option value="{{value}}">{{label}}</option>
                       {{/each}}
                     </select>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <br />
                 <div class="row">
                   <div class="input-group col-sm-12">
                     <label for="reviewedBy">Reviewer</label><br />
                     <select id="reviewedBy" class="form-control input-lg" required>
                       <option  selected="selected" value="">Select Option</option>
                       {{#each usersSelect2}}
                          <option value="{{value}}">{{label}}</option>
                       {{/each}}
                     </select>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <br />
                 <div class="row">
                   <!-- buttons -->
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Assign
                   </button>
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline resetBulkAssignForm">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Reset
                   </button>
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline" data-dismiss="modal">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Close
                   </button>

                 </div>
               </fieldset>
             </form>
           </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: All your selects are `Select2`, correct?

Comment: Yeah you are correct.

Comment: Just to be sure, what exact version of `Select2` is used?

Comment: aldeed:autoform-select2@3.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing value of `Select2`'s underlying `<select>` or `<input>` you have to trigger `change` event so this change will be handled by `Select2` code and rendered appropriately:

```js
$(".bulkAssignForm").find("select").val("").trigger("change");
```

*Successfully tested on [`AutoForm Demo` test page](http://autoform.meteorapp.com/types)*.

Comment: can you help with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469831/search-text-not-displayed-when-select2-changed-to-multiple-selection-mode related to same question but different problem.