# Search text not displayed when Select2 changed to 'multiple' selection mode

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, jquery-select2

To view the code base for problem statement, Kindly [CLICK HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46449665/3296607)

as I set `select` with `id='firmName'` with `multiple` attribute, I am unable to see the text when I type to find specific firm.

Below is the image to support my question.

[image: I type <code>"ajinkyatara"</code> in search box but unable to see it]

I type "ajinkyatara" in search box but unable to see it the text.

How to show the search text string when select2 is in `multiple` selection mode.

Comment: It seems like you are using some theme or modified css which is overriding the default select2 options css. You can try to go to dev tools to inspect & debug the issue yourself. Else create a simple example here that shows the issue.

Comment: Yeah, seems like CSS issue, it's really hard to guess without seeing it live. Perhaps, some video could help?

Comment: You are correct, I am using ADMIN LTE Theme's `modal-primary` here, which is making the text color white.

Answer (score 1):

I found out this post and its sad that it has nothing selected as a solution, as de OP mentioned in a comment this is caused by the color of text being white, you can solve this by aplying this custom css, hope it can help anyone.

```
<style type="text/css">
.select2-search__field {color: black;}
</style>
```