# How to Refresh the Bootstrap modal fields after modal close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap modal with dynamic input fields and i need to empty all the field values after closing the modal.(i.e)i need to refresh the modal once it closed.
I have tried `clear();` and

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
   $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

but not working for me.can you please suggest a working solution for this.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You'll have to get every `<input>` and clear their values. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151044/how-to-clear-all-input-fields-in-bootstrap-modal-when-clicking-data-dismiss-butt) a start

Comment: Thanks Tico , It's working for me...

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through each input in the modal and clear its value:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    $(this).find("input").each(function(input) {
        input.val("");
    })(
});
```

Hopefully this helps!